# Public key authentication in Safari

Tags: authentication, ssl, safari, keychain, public-key

I've implemented public key authentication on my website to allow users to sign in without using a password. They can request a certificate once they're signed in (the normal way). In the backend, a new certificate is generated using a self-signed server certificate. In the Apache config, the client side certificate is set to optional, in order to allow users to sign in without a certificate as well.

This all works splendidly, but there's a problem when visiting the website from Safari. When the website is visited for the first time, the browser offers to use a Apple-generated certificate, and the default Safari option is to do so. My server is of course unable to verify this certificate, because it was signed by Apple and not my server. The result is that users get a certificate error and can't visit the website. If a user denies to use the Apple provided certificate, everything works as expected and the user is able to log in normally.

[image: Safari prompting to use Apple-signed certificate]

The problem is, if the user clicks continue on the first visit (using the Apple-signed certificate), this is remembered in the keychain. This makes the website unaccessible unless one removes the entry in the keychain, which is a pain.

[image: Keychain entry]

Did anyone encounter this error, which makes it virtually impossible to work with public key authentication for the majority of people?